# Excel export displaying '#####...'

Tags: excel, export

I'm trying to export an Excel database into .txt (Tab Delimited), but some of my cells are quite large. When I export into a txt some of the cells are exported as '#######....' which is surprisingly useless.  Has this happened to anyone else? Do you know an easy fix?

Data from one cell of my column:

> Accounting, African Studies, Agricultural/Bioresource Engineering,
>   Agricultural Economics, Agricultural Science, Anatomy/Cell Biology,
>   Animal Biology, Animal Science, Anthropology, Applied Zoology, Architecture,
>   Art History, Atmospheric/Oceanic Science, Biochemistry,
>   Biology, Botanical Sciences, Canadian Studies, Chemical Engineering,
>   Chemistry/Bio-Organic/Environmental/Materials,ChurchMusicPerformance,
>   Civil Engineering/Applied Mechanics, Classics, Composition,
>   Computer Engineering,ComputerScience, ContemporaryGerman Studies,
>   Dietetics, Early Music Performance, Earth/Planetary Sciences, East
>   Asian Studies, Economics, Electrical Engineering, English Literature/
>   Drama/Theatre/Cultural Studies, Entrepreneurship, Environment, Environmental
>   Biology, Finance, Food Science, Foundations of Computing,
>   French Language/Linguistics/Literature/Translation, Geography, Geography/
>   Urban Systems, German, German Language/Literature/Culture,
>   Hispanic Languages/Literature/Culture,History,Humanistic Studies, Industrial
>   Relations, Information Systems, International Business, International
>   Development Studies, Italian Studies/Medieval/Renaissance, Jazz
>   Performance, Jewish Studies, Keyboard Studies, Kindergarten/Elementary
>   Education, Kindergarten/Elementary Education/Jewish Studies,Kinesiology,
>   Labor/Management Relations, Latin American/Caribbean
>   Studies, Linguistics, Literature/Translation, Management Science, Marketing,
>   Materials Engineering,Mathematics,Mathematics/Statistics,Mechanical
>   Engineering, Microbiology, Microbiology/Immunology,
>   Middle Eastern Studies, Mining Engineering, Music, Music Education,
>   MusicHistory,Music Technology,Music Theory,North American Studies,
>   Nutrition,OperationsManagement,OrganizationalBehavior/Human
>   Resources Management, Performing Arts, Philosophy, Physical Education,
>   Physics, Physiology, Plant Sciences, Political Science, Psychology,
>   Quebec Studies, Religious Studies/Scriptures/Interpretations/World
>   Religions,ResourceConservation,Russian, Science for Teachers,Secondary
>   Education, Secondary Education/Music, Secondary Education/Science,
>   SocialWork, Sociology, Software Engineering, Soil Science, Strategic
>   Management, Teaching of French/English as a Second Language,
>   Theology, Wildlife Biology, Wildlife Resources, Women’s Studies.

Comment: More appropriate for http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

1. Go to Google.com/docs
2. Upload your spreadsheet
3. Open the doc and use the file menu to "download as" text format

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to widen the columns?

Answer (score 1):

One of our applications exports as .csv, and we also have that problem.  We have found that saving the document as .xlsx (or .xls, depending on Office version), and then re-opening the .xlsx usually solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I only have like 10 columns so I'm just going to use the excel tools and go column by column to import into mysql